# TYPO3 version 12 FAL in Flexform impty in FLUID

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid, extbase

Following Flexform Konfiguration is working with TYPO3 v11. Now i've upgraded to TYPO3 v12. The Code looks like this:

```
<cardSettings.imageReference>
    <TCEforms>
        <label>
            LLL:EXT:kubus_custom_content/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:tx_kubus_custom_content.flexform.card.image
        </label>
        <config>
            <type>inline</type>
            <foreign_table>sys_file_reference</foreign_table>
            <foreign_field>uid_foreign</foreign_field>
            <foreign_sortby>sorting_foreign</foreign_sortby>
            <foreign_table_field>tablenames</foreign_table_field>
            <foreign_match_fields>
                <fieldname>flexform_imageReference</fieldname>
            </foreign_match_fields>
            <foreign_label>uid_local</foreign_label>
            <foreign_selector>uid_local</foreign_selector>
            <maxitems>1</maxitems>
            <overrideChildTca>
                <columns>
                    <uid_local>
                        <config>
                            <appearance>
                                <elementBrowserType>file</elementBrowserType>
                                <elementBrowserAllowed>gif,jpg,jpeg,bmp,png,pdf,svg,ai
                                </elementBrowserAllowed>
                            </appearance>
                        </config>
                    </uid_local>
                </columns>
                <types type="array">
                    <numIndex index="0" type="array">
                        <showitem>--palette--;;imageoverlayPalette, --palette--;;filePalette
                        </showitem>
                    </numIndex>
                    <numIndex index="1" type="array">
                        <showitem>--palette--;;imageoverlayPalette, --palette--;;filePalette
                        </showitem>
                    </numIndex>
                    <numIndex index="2" type="array">
                        <showitem>--palette--;;imageoverlayPalette, --palette--;;filePalette
                        </showitem>
                    </numIndex>
                    <numIndex index="3" type="array">
                        <showitem>--palette--;;audioOverlayPalette, --palette--;;filePalette
                        </showitem>
                    </numIndex>
                    <numIndex index="4" type="array">
                        <showitem>--palette--;;videoOverlayPalette, --palette--;;filePalette
                        </showitem>
                    </numIndex>
                    <numIndex index="5" type="array">
                        <showitem>--palette--;;imageoverlayPalette, --palette--;;filePalette
                        </showitem>
                    </numIndex>
                </types>
            </overrideChildTca>
            <filter type="array">
                <numIndex index="0" type="array">
                    <userFunc>
                        TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\Filter\FileExtensionFilter->filterInlineChildren
                    </userFunc>
                    <parameters>
                        <allowedFileExtension>gif,jpg,jpeg,bmp,png,pdf,svg,ai</allowedFileExtension>
                    </parameters>
                </numIndex>
            </filter>
            <appearance>
                <useSortable>1</useSortable>
                <headerThumbnail>
                    <field>uid_local</field>
                    <width>45</width>
                    <height>45c</height>
                </headerThumbnail>
                <showPossibleLocalizationRecords>0</showPossibleLocalizationRecords>
                <showRemovedLocalizationRecords>0</showRemovedLocalizationRecords>
                <showSynchronizationLink>0</showSynchronizationLink>
                <showAllLocalizationLink>0</showAllLocalizationLink>
                <enabledControls>
                    <info>1</info>
                    <new>0</new>
                    <dragdrop>1</dragdrop>
                    <sort>0</sort>
                    <hide>1</hide>
                    <delete>1</delete>
                    <localize>1</localize>
                </enabledControls> 
            </appearance>
        </config>
    </TCEforms>
</cardSettings.imageReference>
```

In my TypoScript is this processor:

```
30 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
30 {
    references {
        table = tt_content
        fieldName = flexform_imageReference
    }
    as = card-image
}
```

In TYPO3 v12 the card-image in the FLUID-Templates is always empty. I can't find changes for v12. Does anybody have the same problem? It's the third time now since TYPO3 v10 that i must change the Flexform code for FAL images. That's a bit annoying.

Edit:

Chaged

```
<cardSettings.imageReference>
```

to

```
<flexform_imageReference>
```

Now it works. I just had to change a bit in the FLUID-Template too.

Comment: Where do you get the fieldname "flexform_imageReference" from? Is there any extension that resolves the flexform for you? If so, does it still work the same way or has it changed its behaviour?

Can you do a debug output of the whole data-array to check if the fieldnames are now different or stored in a different place?

Comment: You are right i changed it. Now it works.